# facebook iOS API, check the privacy setting?

Tags: ios, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible for an iOS app to tell if the user has set it to only me, public or friends only?

For example, the basic setting was set to public.
The iOS app would now bring up a post to wall dialog, letting the user add their own text, but on the computer, the user has changed the privacy setting of the app to `Me Only` or `Friends`.

Can the App test for the current privacy setting before the post is made?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @WizKid - after posting from my app, I would like to verify that the post was NOT made "Me only", and I must verify it is made for at least "My Friends"

Comment: Why? If the user want to post to Only me why do you need to know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to check the setting in which a user has shared the post using the Facebook Graph API. But you will need READ STREAM permission from the Facebook API. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/url/) is the reference to the Graph API.

Basically you have to have READ STREAM permission.
You have to share to Facebook and the success callback will give you a post id.
You can use this post id to get all the details related to this post, including the audience (Only Me/Friends/Public).

Comment: I now learn that it may be an issue to use that to verify my post's privacy setting. Is there anything less intrusive I can use to get some info about my post?

Comment: seems like your solution is a right one, yet it is too big for an iOS app. As facebook won't approve this kind of permission.